# Find PID of a process that locked a file

Tags: python, linux, posix

I need to find who locked a file using python (posix/linux). Currently I use this method:

```
flk = struct.pack('hhqql', fcntl.F_WRLCK, 0, 0, 0, 0)
flk = struct.unpack('hhqql', fcntl.fcntl(self.__file, fcntl.F_GETLK , flk))

if flk[0] == fcntl.F_UNLCK:
    # file is unlocked ...
else:
    pid = flk[4]
```

This solution is not architecture-independent. Structure passed to fcntl contains fields such as off_t or pid_t. I cannot make assumptions about sizes of those types.

```
struct flock {
    ...
    short l_type;    /* Type of lock: F_RDLCK,
                    F_WRLCK, F_UNLCK */
    short l_whence;  /* How to interpret l_start:
                    SEEK_SET, SEEK_CUR, SEEK_END */
    off_t l_start;   /* Starting offset for lock */
    off_t l_len;     /* Number of bytes to lock */
    pid_t l_pid;     /* PID of process blocking our lock
                    (F_GETLK only) */
    ...
};
```

Is there any other way to find the PID? Or maybe sizes of off_t and pid_t? The solution must be fully **portable** between different architectures.

**Edit**
I decided to use *lsof* program as suggested below. Another option is to parse /proc/locks file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can try use external program, lsof, to do that?

> ```
>    Lsof revision 4.85 lists on its standard output file information 
>    about files opened by processes for the following UNIX dialects:
>
>         AIX 5.3
>         Apple Darwin 9 and Mac OS X 10.[56]
>         FreeBSD 4.9 and 6.4 for x86-based systems
>         FreeBSD 8.[02] and 9.0 for AMD64-based systems
>         Linux 2.1.72 and above for x86-based systems
>         Solaris 9, 10 and 11
> ```

Comment: pbs module is nice for calling external utilities: pbs.lsof('/path/to/some/file')

Answer (score 0):

I had previously used `'hhllh'` because I thought it would most closely map to `off_t` across platforms.  But eventually I settled on `'hhqqh'`, which works for me on 32bit and 64bit systems.

I was surprised by this solution, but what seems to be going on for the the 32bit boxes I was looking at is `bits/fcntl.h` creates the `flock` struct with `off64_t` unless the system already defines `__USE_FILE_OFFSET64` (in which case it just uses the regular 'ol `off_t`) so it seems like the size of `l_start` and `l_len` is always 8 (the python struct format char `'q'` is `long long`).

This is probably not entirely portable, I can't say all modern 32bit systems are going to do this, but it was good enough for me for now - so I thought I'd mention it in case others (like myself) would rather not have to exec another process and do a bunch of string parsing, YMMV.  Also if I'm misunderstanding (or poorly explaining) why this format string seems to work on both platforms - maybe someone could correct me?